# keras model.get_weight is not returning results in expected dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am doing classification over mnist dataset using keras. I am interested in doing some operation on weight matrix generated after the training but some layers weight matrix looks like they are not fully connected.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1000, input_shape = (train_x.shape[1],), activation='relu' ))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_x,train_y, epochs=10, validation_data= (test_x,test_y))

w = model.get_weights()

for i in range(5):
        print(w[i].shape)
```

now, when I print the dimensions of the weight matrix of each layer I get the following result

```
(784, 1000)
(1000,)
(1000, 1000)
(1000,)
(1000, 500)
```

why 2nd has (1000,) and not (1000,1000)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is bias. Don't forget that layer is defined by [image] (sometimes also written as [image]).

Suppose the shape of `x` is `(None, 784)` and the shape of weights `w` is `(784, 1000)`. The `matmul(x, w)` operation results in the shape `(None, 1000)`. To the resulted tensor of this shape you're adding bias of shape `(1000, )` which is broadcasted along  the `None` dimension.