# Neural network output issue

Tags: tensorflow

I built a neural network with tensorflow, here the code :

```py
class DQNetwork:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size, learning_rate, name='DQNetwork'):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate

        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            # We create the placeholders

            self.inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[state_size[1], state_size[0]], name="inputs")
            self.actions_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.action_size], name="actions_")

            # Remember that target_Q is the R(s,a) + ymax Qhat(s', a')
            self.target_Q = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], name="target")


            self.fc = tf.layers.dense(inputs = self.inputs_,
                                      units = 50,
                                      kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
                                      activation = tf.nn.elu)


            self.output = tf.layers.dense(inputs = self.fc, 
                                        units = self.action_size,
                                        kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
                                        activation=None)



            # Q is our predicted Q value.
            self.Q = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(self.output, self.actions_))

            # The loss is the difference between our predicted Q_values and the Q_target
            # Sum(Qtarget - Q)^2
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.target_Q - self.Q))

            self.optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)
```

But i have an issue with the output,

the output should normaly be at the same size than "action_size", and action_size value is 3
but i got an output like [[5][3]] instead of just [[3]] and i realy don't understand why...

This network got 2 dense layers, one with 50 perceptrons and the other with 3 perceptrons (= action_size).

state_size is format : [[9][5]]

If someone know why my output is two dimensions i will be very thankful

Comment: Please provide the actual values of the shapes (what is `self.action_size`, `state_size[1], state_size[0]` etc)

Comment: self.action_size is like the possibles "actions" to perform, currently i have : action_size = 3   state_size = [9, 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `self.inputs_` placeholder has shape `(5, 9)`. You perform the `matmul(self.inputs_, fc1.w)` operation in  dense layer `fc1` which has shape `(9, 50`) and it results in shape `(5, 50)`. You then apply another dense layer with shape `(50, 3)` which results in output shape `(5, 3)`.

The same schematically:

1. `matmul(shape(5, 9), shape(9, 50))  ---> shape(5, 50)` `# output of 1st dense layer`
2. `matmul(shape(5, 50), shape(50, 3)) ---> shape(5, 3)` `# output of 2nd dense layer`

Usually, the first dimension of the input placeholder represents batch size and the second dimension is the dimension of inputs feature vector. So for each sample in a batch you (batch size is 5 in your case) you get the output shape 3.

To get probabilities, use this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

inputs_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 9))
actions_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))

fc = tf.layers.dense(inputs=inputs_, units=2)
output = tf.layers.dense(inputs=fc, units=3)
reduced = tf.reduce_mean(output, axis=0)
probs = tf.nn.softmax(reduced) # <--probabilities

inputs_vals = np.ones((5, 9))
actions_vals = np.ones((1, 3))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    print(probs.eval({inputs_:inputs_vals,
                      actions_:actions_vals}))
    # [0.01858923 0.01566187 0.9657489 ]
```

Comment: Thank a lot for ur answer ! ok i think i have understand but still one thing i didn't : why shape(9,50) results in shape(5,50) by the first dense layer ?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55561583/5154274). If you still won't understand I'll explain.

Comment: `matmul(shape(5, 9), shape(9, 50)) ---> shape(5, 50)`

Comment: Ok so what if i want the ouput of the last layer to only be (3) ? because what i thought is that the "units" value only is the amount of perceptrons, i don't understand the two dimensional gesture

Comment: Do you want to reduce the first axis? If so, use `tf.reduce_sum(output, axis=0)` for sum and `tf.reduce_mean(output, axis=0)` for mean.

Comment: What i want to do is fed my net with a batch of inputs which both have a size of 9 and after two fully connected layer i want to get 3 probability that's all, that's why i use two dense layers, i don't understand how and why the "units" value modify the dimension of the output, for me if we set the units value to '50' we will have an output like (50) and not (50, something)

Comment: you want unique action for every input in a batch? OR one action for the whole batch of inputs?

Comment: I want 3 probabilites as output for the whole batch not 3 probabilities for each inputs in the batch